# How to create the following responsive layout with bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I want to achieve these:

Computer view:

[image: Computer view]

Tablet Portrait view:

[image: Tablet Portrait view]

Mobile Portrait view:

[image: Mobile Portrait view]

Currently I have this following code, where the "home-content" part will generate the items#1-items#X:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../_lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../_lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../_lib/normalize.css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <script src="../_lib/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../_lib/jquery/jquery.fittext.js"></script>
    <script src="../_lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    init();
</script>
<div class="home-bg"></div>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="home-noti">
                <div class="news-noti">
                    <div class="news-panel panel">
                        <div class="news-title panel-heading">
                            <h2 class="panel-title">NEWSFLASH!</h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="news-items-wrapper">
                            <ul id="news-items" class="news-items list-group"></ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div id="home-content" class="home-content"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

This piece of code can achieve the "Computer view" and "Tablet Portrait view". I could have done it in using 4 of "col-md-3" but that will mean sometimes I might get Notifications col with 2 items on the same row OR Notifications col with 1 item on the same row, which is not what I want. How do I achieve the "Mobile Portrait view" without breaking the layout of the previous 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use nested columns for this.

```
row
  col-*-*
    row
      col-*-*
    row
      col-*-*
```

Review the [Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting) and view working example at Full Screen then reduce the viewport.

```css
/**FOR DEMO PURPOSES ONLY**/

html,
body {
  margin-top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
.alert.alert-info {
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 0;
}
.alert.alert-info-tall {
  height: 340px;
  border-radius: 0;
}
/**FOR DEMO PURPOSES ONLY**/
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="alert alert-info alert-info-tall">Notifications</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-8">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="alert alert-info">1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="alert alert-info">2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="alert alert-info">3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="alert alert-info">4</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="alert alert-info">5</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="alert alert-info">6</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="alert alert-info">7</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="alert alert-info">8</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="alert alert-info">9</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can u explain why u chose "col-lg-4" and "col-lg-8"? I don't understand this part.

Comment: The purpose of those are to separate your columns so they stand next to each other. The sizes you choose are essentially how you would like the content to be distributed: if you want both sides even use col-*-6 for each, if you want a different break point use col-md-*. If you adjust those numbers (so they equal 12: 6 with 6, 9 with 3 etc) you'll see how it's working.

Comment: Oh cos u used 1:2, i actually intended to have 1:3. The col-sm- part is working with the col-md- i hv chosen. Cos i don't understand why u changed col-md- to col-lg-. But it seems the same if the ratio is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Try to figure out [Bootstrap Gird Options](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options) and
you just Need to know when to use which class for which screen and you are good to go.
Here is the working [structure](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PPJqQa) for your reference.

```
 <div class="row">
  <div class="left-block col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-xs-12">
    Aside Section
  </div>
  <div class="content-block col-lg-8 col-md-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="row" style="padding:10px;">
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12" style="border:1px solid">Item 1</div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12" style="border:1px solid">Item 2</div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12" style="border:1px solid">Item 3</div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12" style="border:1px solid">Item 4</div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12" style="border:1px solid">Item 5</div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12" style="border:1px solid">Item 6</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="col-xs-12 notification">
            <p>Notifications</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                <div class="col-xs-12 item">
                    <p>Item # 1</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                <div class="col-xs-12 item">
                    <p>Item # 2</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                <div class="col-xs-12 item">
                    <p>Item # 3</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                <div class="col-xs-12 item">
                    <p>Item # 4</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                <div class="col-xs-12 item">
                    <p>Item # 5</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                <div class="col-xs-12 item">
                    <p>Item # 6</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                <div class="col-xs-12 item">
                    <p>Item # 7</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                <div class="col-xs-12 item">
                    <p>Item # 8</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                <div class="col-xs-12 item">
                    <p>Item # 9</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this style will help to get a better look :

```
.notification {
    background-color:#000;
    height:auto;
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom:50px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
.item {
    background-color:#333;
    height: auto;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
p {
    color:#ffffff;
}
```

Here is the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/xwmmfu0e/

Answer (score -1):

You need to add an xs prefix. Try this adding col-xs-6 to both divs.

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
...
</div>
...
<div class="col-md-9 col-xs-6">
            ...
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, this doesn't work. Whether how i resize the window, i get notification column and 3 items on the same row.